# Kirchhoff's Laws on Series-Parallel Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel, differential, series, kirchhoffs-laws

Consider the circuit

[image]

The writing in red are my own additions (so let me know if it's wrong).

From Kirchhoff's Laws, I obtained

\$I=I_{2}+I_{1}\$

\$I_{1}=I_{3}+I_{4}\$

\$V=V_{C_{1}}=V_{R_{2}}=V_{C_{2}}\$

\$V=R_{1}I=R_{3}I_{4}\$

\$I_{2}=C_{1}\frac{d}{dt}V_{C_{1}}\$

\$V_{R_{2}}=R_{2}I_{3}\$

\$I_{4}=C_{2}\frac{d}{dt}V_{C_{2}}\$

Did I get it right? Again, I'm not really sure as I'm not entirely familiar with circuits and the sort, being a mathematician rather than an electrical engineer.

In the end I want to come up with a differential equation that links \$V\$ with \$V_{C_{2}}\$, but I imagine that I can reach that via elimination, provided I have these equations right.

Comment: You've missed the voltage drops in R1 and R3, I think. V = IR1 + VC1, and VC2 will be different than VC1 due to R3.

Comment: I1 = I3 + I4 (not I2) so no you got it wrong. Anyway, you haven't said what you are trying to solve for. Are you sure you are a mathematician or is it that you think you are?

Comment: @Andyaka If you must know, I'm trying to determine the input/state/output equations and the differential equation which describes the input/output behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

\$I=I_{2}+I_{1}\$

\$I_{1}=I_{3}+I_{4}\$

\$\$

\$V=V_{C_{1}}+V_{R_{1}}\$

\$V=\frac{1}{C_{1}}\int I_{2}\mathrm{d}t+R_{1}I\$

\$\$

\$V_{R_{2}} = V_{C_{1}}\$

\$R_{2}I_{3} = \frac{1}{C_{1}}\int I_{2}\mathrm{d}t\$

\$\$

\$V_{R_{2}}=V_{R_{3}}+V_{C_{2}}\$

\$\$

\$V_{R_{3}}+V_{C_{2}}=V_{R_{2}}\$

\$R_{3}I_{4}+\frac{1}{C_{2}}\int I_{4}\mathrm{d}t=R_{2}I_{3}\$

The rest should be a math excercise, I think :-)

Comment: Can you find the equation linking \$V\$ and \$V_{C_{2}}\$, because I can't with your system of equations?

Comment: You are right, that's missing. I inserted it. \$V_{R_{2}}=V_{R_{3}}+V_{C_{2}}\$

Comment: Are there any major differences in the equations if we were to take an output voltage across \$C_{2}\$ (and input voltage the usual \$V\$)?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "take an ouptut voltage" exactly. If we imagine that you only measure the voltage and there's no current, then there's no difference. But if you connect any device (some load or a voltmeter), you have to add this as parallel resistor next to \$C_{2}\$. The equations are then changing accordingly. So in real life, it definitely makes a difference if you connect a load.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.  I think it'll help a bit to rearrange the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frjgGO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So you end up with:

V = V<sub>R1</sub> + V'

V' = V<sub>C1</sub> = V<sub>R2</sub> = V<sub>R3</sub> + V<sub>C2</sub>

And if we define the total current produced by the voltage source I<sub>V</sub>...

I<sub>V</sub> = I<sub>R1</sub>

I<sub>R3</sub> = I<sub>C2</sub>

I<sub>V</sub> = I<sub>C1</sub> + I<sub>R2</sub> + I<sub>R3</sub>

Comment: And what about the current (since I want a differential equation linking V and I)?

Comment: Do my contitutive equations still hold?